# Meaning of (*(__IO uint16_t*)PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS) variable declaration

Tags: stm32, c, c++

There is a variable declaration:

```
uint16_t status = (*(__IO uint16_t*)PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS);
```

`__IO` is the precompiler directive that becomes the keyword `volatile`. `PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS` is the hex address, say 0x08000000;

I can't get my head around what this statement actually does. Anyone help please?

Comment: This question has been asked many times over on https://stackoverflow.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS` is an integer value; the subexpression `(__IO uint16_t*)PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS)` expands to `(volatile uint16_t*)PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS)`, which casts the integer to a volatile pointer to 16-bit unsigned integer.

Finally, the outermost asterisk is used to deference this pointer. Overall, the statement reads a 16-bit integer from the given address, considering it as a pointer to volatile memory<sup>1</sup>, meaning that it must be read/written from memory each time it is accessed (i.e. the compiler should not cache it in a register or assume that its value remains the same each time the given code is executed).

<sup>1</sup> Not the same as a volatile pointer to normal memory (i.e. `uint16_t * volatile`)

Comment: i didn't quite get what's the use of first casting `int` to a volatile pointer and then dereferencing it. could you please explain?

Comment: @DimaDz The de-referencing is simply there to allow you to access the contents of the register. Apparently it is a 16 bit register, hence the uint16_t.

Comment: @DimaDz The integer in question is the address, expressed as an integer. C/C++ doesn't allow you to directly dereference it as if it were a pointer (i.e. `*someInt`) is no good, since the type/size of data that ought to be read is unclear. Instead, the integer must first be cast to a pointer to volatile uint16_t, so the compiler knows to generate code that reads a uint16_t from the given location, without assuming that the value remains the same between reads (volatility)

Answer (score 2):

Take the number `0x08000000`, type-cast it as a pointer to a `volatile uint16_t`, then dereference that pointer to read the value at the address `0x08000000` in memory and put the result in the `status` variable.

`volatile` tells your compiler that the value stored at this address may change "unexpectedly" and that it can't just read he value once and store it in a register and use that stored value in future - it must re-read the value form the address in memory every time it's used.

This type of code is typical in microcontrollers when referring to peripheral registers - particularly status registers and data receive registers where the values contained in those registers depend on external events which are not known or predictable to/by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It casts the address to a pointer which points to a 16-bit word. It then refers to it by reading the 16-bit word (from the address where the pointer points). The value is stored in the variable.